# How to create and Oracle trigger to return some DB Error code, not the Custom Exception but real DB ERROR?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to know is it possible to return a DB ERROR code from trigger, rather than Custom exception created with RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. I have some requirement where i need to return an DB ERROR code like 1 for Unique Constraint. I have a purpose to ask this, because for some reason with some hash based partition we are not creating unique constraints on table and rather have one trigher with which i want to return Unique constraint as an error code after checking if the record exists in DB.

Comment: "return Unique constraint as an error code after checking if the record exists in DB" do you think this possible ? its not possible to find PK /uniqu constraint error in multie user evnvironemnt .

Comment: The primary key index can ONLY be local IF and ONLY IF, the primary key is in fact the (or part of the) partition key https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:18741227819236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RAISE DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
```

Only in this case you can't pass any arguments to this error and you will get:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated

Comment: Great Janis, That seems to work but it return other 2 errors as well, which relates to triger then, with something like ORA-06512 at "BLAH BLA", line X and ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'Name of the trigger'

Comment: This is standard Oracle behaviour. This kind of stuff will be returned also when you use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`

Comment: Righto, great help. Thanks Janis.